# Modify phone number in file

Tags: text-processing, sed

Let say I have the following phone number in a .txt file

```
(682) 543-7890
```

I need three sed commands to change this number.

1. Need the number in-between parentheses (can be any number) to replace with 800
   Example text:

```
(800) 543-7890
```

2. next I need to remove the parentheses.
   Example text:

```
800 543-7890
```

3. For the last part I need a dash to be added in the white space between the area code and the rest of the number.
   Example text:

```
800-543-7890
```

I tried `sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'` so far and it removes the parentheses and everything inside.

Comment: Why does it have to be sed and why can't it be done in one command instead of three?  Also obligatory "what have you tried so far?"

Comment: It's part of an assignment and needs to be a .sed file of multiple commands. if it possible to be done in one so be it. I tried sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g' so far (I'm not the smartest working with sed) and it removes the parentheses and everything inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'` could almost work, just have to do a few adjustments:

```bsh
# You don't need greedy command 'g'
# you have to account for the space
# you have to make the substitution
$ sed -e 's/([^()]*) */800-/'
800-543-7890
```

Of course as demonstrated by the accepted answer, there are simpler ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Single `sed` invocation is enough:

```
sed 's/(.*) */800-/'
```